# Error: window.toolbar is not available in packaged apps in Google Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Good day. I'm trying to port my site for Chrome App. When I run my application errors appear, though I do not use these components:

```
window.toolbar is not available in packaged apps.
window.statusbar is not available in packaged apps.
window.scrollbars is not available in packaged apps.
window.personalbar is not available in packaged apps.
window.menubar is not available in packaged apps.
window.locationbar is not available in packaged apps.
```

Tried to add manifest.json line: "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'", but the errors persist. Tell me please, what can I do?

Comment: Are you enumerating the properties of `window` at some point?

Answer (score 3):

Some web APIs are disabled for Chrome Apps.

See the list here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated

I guess your problem falls into "Browser chrome APIs" (the confusing term "chorme" is used in the original meaning "the parts of a web browser's user interface other than the web page it is showing").

The listed workaround is: N/A, meaning this API is completely disabled and you need to implement features you need yourself. How you do that depends on what you were trying to do.

Since the APIs above basically tell you which parts of the UI are shown, you don't need them in a Chrome app, since you're in complete control of the window yourself. You can always assume a certain state.